# Can I use the curl in the python project?

Tags: python, curl

In my terminal, I can use `curl` command, such as:

```
$ curl 'http://www.sohu.com'
```

it will download the source code of the web page.

But I want to execute the `curl` in my python project. 
Whether is it can be realize?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the lib urllib2 to accomplish the same:

[urllib2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#module-urllib2)